# Issue with BIRT - open script SQL error

Tags: sql, database, eclipse, birt, maximo

Hi I am following a tutorial and I have inserted this code into the open script in BIRT Eclipse.

```
maximoDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), this.getName());
maximoDataSet.open();

var sqlText = new String();

// Add query to sqlText variable.
sqlText = " select workorder.wonum, workorder.description, workorder.status, workorder.worktype, "
+ " workorder.wopriority, workorder.reportdate, workorder.estdur, workorder.location "
+ " from workorder "
// Include the Maximo where clause
+ " where " + params["where"]
;

maximoDataSet.setQuery(sqlText);
```

However I am receiving the following error when trying to preview the report:

> ReportDesign (id = 1):
>   + There are errors evaluating script "maximoDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(),
>   this.getName()); maximoDataSet.open();
>
> var sqlText = new String();
>
> // Add query to sqlText variable. sqlText = " select workorder.wonum,
>   workorder.description, workorder.status, workorder.worktype, "
>   + " workorder.wopriority, workorder.reportdate, workorder.estdur, workorder.location "
>   + " from workorder " // Include the Maximo where clause
>   + " where " + params["where"] ;
>
> maximoDataSet.setQuery(sqlText);": Fail to execute script in function
>   __bm_OPEN(). Source:
>   ------ " + maximoDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(),
>   this.getName()); maximoDataSet.open();
>
> var sqlText = new String();
>
> // Add query to sqlText variable. sqlText = " select workorder.wonum,
>   workorder.description, workorder.status, workorder.worktype, "
>   + " workorder.wopriority, workorder.reportdate, workorder.estdur, workorder.location "
>   + " from workorder " // Include the Maximo where clause
>   + " where " + params["where"] ;
>
> maximoDataSet.setQuery(sqlText); + "
>   ----- A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information. Wrapped
>   com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.report.script.MXReportRuntimeException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   (/report/data-sets/script-data-set[@id="5"]/method[@name="open"]#2).

Does anyone know why this may be?

Thanks.

Comment: There should be more of the stack trace that should reveal more of what happened.

Comment: what value did you specify for the parameter where? You can't leave it empty. Use 1=1 and try again. Otherwise provide full stack trace

Answer (score -2):

check your connect to database, sure connect sussefull